# Fastest method to handle dbf from C#

Tags: c#, dbf

I use OLEDB to insert data to a DB4 .dbf file. Inserting 5,500 rows takes approximately 2.5 min. So I need a faster way to implement it as my data will have upto 80,000 rows and time taken will be too painful. Is there any alternative faster ways to do this? According to your view which is the best way?

PS: Please mention the aprox. time taken for your method if possible

Comment: Are you using a single transaction for all inserts or one transaction per insert?

Comment: inserting multiple rows within a single query could speed up a lot your work...

Comment: @Joey: no I am inserting row by row.

Comment: edit your insert script/app according to my answer and you'll see results :)

Comment: @Joey: I tried making it a single transaction. Still it is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting multiple rows within a single query could speed up **a lot** your work.
For example: I've just tried inserting 100,000 rows using 100,000 INSERT and using 1,000 INSERT with 100 rows each one: I have a speed-up about 100!!
Difference is using

```
INSERT INTO table (....) VALUES (...)
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table (....) VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...),(...),...
```

So edit your inserting function to use 100 (for example) records at a time.

Comment: @Vicky: did you tried this solution? Did you find some improvement or not?

Comment: @Marco: I am not able to insert it as a single query as the column names to be inserted differs for each row :(

Comment: @Vicky: how it is possible in a database to save rows with different column names? I didn't know it was possible. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean :)

Comment: My mistake. I was inserting each row by removing the cell (column) with empty value. So the query was diff each time. I am trying to modify it as you said. will try :D

Comment: I am not able to do it. when I use as u told it is giving a "Missing semicolon(;) at the end" error :(

Comment: @Vicky: oh gosh, you have to close your query with a semicolon, always!! Anyway, post an example and I'll correct that

Comment: ofcourse I did it. Still it gives the error :( Eg: INSERT INTO table (index, name) values (110, 'Vicky'), (111, 'Marco'); Are you sure you can insert multiples rows in this format in DB4 .dbf file??

Comment: @Vicky: edit your post inserting database schema and I'll try to create same db and insert... If you can post event only the rows you establish connection and insert records...

Comment: @Marco, I'm almost positive that OleDB does not support multi-line inserts in a single SQL query...  Each has to be submitted separately.

Comment: @Vicky: gotta try that and another way I've in my mind. Tomorrow (here is evening) I give you an answer.

Comment: @Marco: Wt about the answer u told about :(

Comment: @Vicky: you're right, but I had some trouble with my children... I'll do that as promised...

Comment: @Vicky: using OleDB is not possible to use syntax I gave you, sorry. You can find a useful workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504/is-there-any-way-to-create-multiple-insert-statements-in-a-ms-access-query)

Comment: @Marco or Vicky did you ever get this to work with the workaround you posted in the link above?