# Missing Semicolon at the end of sql statement Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to execute the following code. However, I continue to recieve the following 'Missing semicolon (;) at the end of SQL statement error in Microsoft Access.

The first query creates the table with the columns defined.

```
create table test 
(
    ProcessID int, 
    Name varchar(10),  
    Address varchar(10),    
    RandomData varchar(10)
);
```

The second query is causing the missing semicolon error.

```
INSERT into test 
VALUES (123 , 'TestName', 'TestAdd', 'qwrj3ri'), 
       (456 , 'TestName2', 'TestAdd', 'qwerty'),    
       (789 , 'TestName', 'TestAdd', 'qwrj3ri'),    
       (1234, 'Testing123', 'tester', 'asdfghjk');
```

Comment: See the syntax highlighting? It points out your missing single quote next to the end of your insert.

Comment: I don't think access supports multiple rows in the `values`.

Comment: `,  T` superfluous character on end of first set of values & `sdfg');` - missing open quote.  These are causing the issue / SQL's trying to guess the error but isn't intelligent enough to display the real error.  Fix those issues and you're good.

Comment: In Access SQL, `INSERT ... VALUES` allows you to insert only one row, as Damien suggested.

Comment: Despite correcting the errors. It continues to display the error. Thanks guys! Looks like I will have to enter the data manually.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your amended code - we may spot something else.  Also, is there code before or after that insert line; perhaps that's where the issue's lurking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code with amendments per above comments to make it Access friendly & remove typos:

```
INSERT INTO test ( ProcessID, Name, Address, RandomData)
VALUES (123 , 'TestName', 'TestAdd', 'qwrj3ri');

INSERT INTO test ( ProcessID, Name, Address, RandomData)
VALUES (456 , 'TestName2', 'TestAdd', 'qwerty');    

INSERT INTO test ( ProcessID, Name, Address, RandomData)
VALUES (789 , 'TestName', 'TestAdd', 'qwrj3ri'); 

INSERT INTO test ( ProcessID, Name, Address, RandomData)
VALUES (1234, 'Testing123', 'tester', 'asdfghjk');
```

Useful reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243852(v=office.12).aspx

**Specific comments:**

@Damien_The_Unbeliever:

> I don't think access supports multiple rows in the values.

Amended to include an `insert into` per row instead of a value set per row (`values (...), (...)`).

@Thomas Tschernich:

> our missing single quote next to the end of your insert

Changed `'tester', sdfg')` to `'tester', 'sdfg');`

@JohnLBevan:

> superfluous character on end of first set of values

Changed `'qwrj3ri'), T` to `'qwrj3ri'),`

Comment: Thanks John. I think its because I was not familiar with access sql. I actually had first written the code in mysql as I was mroe familiar with it and tried to translate it into sql code for access. Basically I was making a test file and running sql queries before actually importanting an excel document where I could work with the real data. Unfortunately, I am not sure I am able to translate all my mysql queries sucessfully.

Comment: No worries; I'm familiar with avoiding Access / tend to write my code in T-SQL (SQL Server) then translate from working code.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert multiple rows in one insert statement in SQL server,but in MS ACCESS its **not possible** as above listed.

> More techniques on multiple inserts in access are described
>   beautifully [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162982/insert-multiple-rows-using-one-insert-statement-in-access-2010)