# MS Access insert multiple rows

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, insert-into

For a project I want to use a query to insert multiple rows into a table. I found several threads on how to do this, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504/is-there-any-way-to-create-multiple-insert-statements-in-a-ms-access-query/65027#65027), that were really helpful but I still can't figure it out how to insert multiple rows.

The SQL code that I currently have doesn't cause any syntax error, but it just doesn't insert any rows.

My table that I want to insert into looks like:

```
create table SYT_ABRDAT
(
    id integer primary key not null,
    beginper integer,
    eindper integer,
    periode text,
    groep bit
)
```

The query that I'm currently using (I made it shorter):

```
insert into syt_abrdat (id, begindat, einddat, periode, groep) 
    select * 
    from
        (select top 1 
             "1" as id, "9999" as begindat, "9999" as einddat,
             "---" as periode, "1" as groep 
         from 
             onerow 
         union all
         select top 1 
             "2" as id, "9999" as begindat, "9999" as einddat,
             "XXX" as periode, "1" as groep 
         from 
             onerow
        )
```

Solution:

I added an empty row into table `onerow` instead of filling it with some data.

This is necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO syt_abrdat (id,begindat,einddat,periode,groep) 
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT TOP 1 1 AS id, 9999 AS begindat, 9999 as einddat, '---' as periode, 'WAAR' as groep FROM onerow UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 1 2 AS id, 9999 AS begindat, 9999 as einddat, 'XXX' as periode, 'WAAR' as groep FROM onerow)
```

Comments:

- Use single quotes for literal string values
- Do not use quotes for literal numbers
- the table `onerow` must contain at least 1 record

Comment: that would normally work in other databases but ms access won't allow multiple insert statements. You can trick this with a union. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62504/is-there-any-way-to-create-multiple-insert-statements-in-a-ms-access-query/65027#65027

Comment: @B.Termeer - I missed that, thanks. Looking at that question are you sure that the table you are referencing (`onerow`) has 1 row? If there are none then this would be an expected result (no records inserted).

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried it but still get the problem that zero rows are added. I will check the table onerow. If i added one rowI will post the tabel structure of onerow

Comment: @B.Termeer - the table structure of `onerow` does not matter as long as there is a record in the table.

Comment: thanks for your response. I added a empty row instead filling it with at least something.